# pylint Cannot import custom module and function (no-name-in-module)

Tags: python, pylint

I have the structure:

```
 |- file run_app.py

 |- folder 'tasks'

 |-- file app.py
```

There is a string in `run_app.py`:

```
import tasks.app
```

And pylint alerts that

```
run_app.py:8:0: E0611: No name 'app' in module 'tasks' (no-name-in-module)
```

When I rename `tasks` to `taskss`, the error disappears. Whats this? How to fix this strange behavior if I want to name the folder exactly 'tasks'?

Comment: The name `tasks` is already a python module

Comment: I am not sure:

python

Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 

[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tasks

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'

>>>

Comment: can you try: `from tasks import app`? have you also included an `init` in the folder named `tasks` ?

Comment: see alos this concerning the `init` file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/5025009

Comment: __init__ helped, thanks. And the link is helpful too

Comment: glad that i could help. i posted a more complete answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to include an `__init__.py` file in the folder.

**Reason:**

The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages.

Structure:

```
package_name/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
  subpackage/
    other.py
```

---

More info and examples here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to @makis answer:
`__init__.py` were required to make a folder a package until python 3.2:

```
package_name/
  __init__.py <- makes package_name a package
  foo.py
```

But if you are in Python 3.3+ using `__init__.py` that way may generate *pylint* 
"no name in module" error:

```
package_name/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
  subpackage/
    other.py
```

`from package_name.subpackage import other` will generate the mentioned error.
 If you remove that `__init__.py`, *pylint* stops warning you.

My source:
http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html